# opening an image inside an modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubendra/TSc8E/)

I am trying to create an image gallery. I want my each image to open up inside a modal window when someone click on any image. I have designed my modal window. i just don't know how to connect my modal window to my images in the image gallery. I want the clicked-in image to appear inside the `img` tag of my modal window.

This is my first time i am trying to do something with modal window. i have no idea how to write that click event handler for my case. I searched in net. I did not find any matching solution. All were suggesting to use their own plugins. I don't want to use others plugins for this. A little help would be appreciated.

Here's is my image gallery

```
<div class="gallery">
   <div class="row">
     <a href="#"> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </a>
     <a href="#"> <img class="wideimage" src=""> </a>
     <!--more images-->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <a href="#"> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </a>
     <a href="#"> <img class="normalimage" src=""> </a>
     <!--more images-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my modal window

```
<div class="gallery-overlay" style="display: none;">
<div class="gallery-imagebox">
    <img class="gallery-image" src="#">
</div>

<div class="gallery-captionbox">
    <div class="gallery-control gallery-control-previous">
    <
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-control gallery-control-next">
    >
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the click event handler?

Comment: @Precastic actually, this is my first time i am trying to do something with modal window. i have no idea how to write that click event handler for my case. i searched in net. did not find any matching solution. a little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could start with this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.gallery').on('click','a',function(){
    $('.gallery-overlay').show()
      .find('.gallery-image').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

Have a look at this [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSc8E/5/)

Comment: it did not work for me. i changed your code as find('.gallery-image').attr('src',$(this).find('a').attr('href')); as i wanted open up the image location i specified in href attribute of anchor tag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shubendra/TSc8E/3/ check this jsfiddle to get to know what is happening

Comment: @Aadietya If you are going to do that then you want to return false so that the link doesn't get loaded. I have updated my answer & the fiddle in my answer. I have also use the .on handler because that is cleaner for the same click handler on multiple elements.

Comment: @Aadietya You might also want to look at this plugin if you want the effect to be nicer when you click on the images... http://fancybox.net/